# Support for 'Dart' snippets

Tags: dart, flutter, code-snippets

I would like to support Dart snippets in VS Code.  I'd also like to do so using something like the Snippet Creator (https://github.com/nikitaKunevich/vscode-snippet-creator)  but this doesn't seem to work as 'dart' is not a language option.  Is it possible to add 'dart' as an option so that I can use the snippet creator to have snippets in '*.dart' files?

Comment: I'd recommend filing an issue on the github repo - this isn't something that can be solved on stack overflow

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure if this was as simple as a settings entry I could add or if it was going to take more than that.  I'm trying to find a contact on the VS Code team internally here to see what it will take too.

Answer (score 2):

control+shift+p >snippets > dart.json add this code

```
{
    "stateless": {
      "prefix": "fless",
      "body": [
        "import 'package:flutter/material.dart';",
        "class $1 extends StatelessWidget {",
        "\t@override",
        "\tWidget build(BuildContext context) {",
        "\t\treturn Container(",
        "\t\t\t$2",
        "\t\t);",
        "\t}",
        "}"
      ]
    },

    "stateful": {
      "prefix": "ffull",
      "body": [
        "import 'package:flutter/material.dart';",
        "class $1 extends StatefulWidget {",
        "\t@override",
        " \t_$1State createState() => _$1State();",
        "}",

        "class _$1State extends State<$1> {",
        " \t@override",
        " \tWidget build(BuildContext context) {",
        "\t\treturn Container(",
        " \t\t\t$2",
        "\t\t);",
        "\t}",
        "} "
      ]
    }
```

}
//control+shift+p >snippets > dart.json add this code